# Raise Event when a Function return True

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, serial-port, backgroundworker

Part of a program I am modifying involves communicating through a serial port using a proprietary library. Unfortunately, this library does not have the same [SerialPort.DataReceived event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) that the System.IO.Ports namespace contains. In fact, it has no events whatsoever, however it does have two functions that can probably be used similarly:

1. Port.WaitForData(int time)

   This function waits the given amount of time to recieve some previously specified strings over the port. It returns 1 for *yes, received string*, or 0 for *no, did not recieve string, timed out*.
2. Port.IsReceiveBufferEmpty()

   This function returns a boolean of *yes, the receive buffer is empty* or *no, the receive buffer contains data*.

It seems to me I will have to create some thread to be continuously looping whenever the port is opened and do one of these two things:

1. For every loop, call WaitForData(some big number) with the specified strings it is looking for set to "", or vbCrLf, or something else that I can confirm it will recieve everytime data is sent. If it finds smoething, read it and write to a textbox. If WaitForData doesn't find anything, loop again.
2. For every loop, call IsReceiveBufferEmpty(), and if it isn't, read it and write to a textbox.

What the best way to go about implementing this? The first options seems potentially more efficient to me, although I know next to nothing about how these method work under the hood. Obviously I want to keep my form responsive when doing this, so how should I go about continuously looping without freezing the form but being able to read any incoming data?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: writing such an API for general use would be different than optimizing it for whatever app you are writing.  we know nothing about your app.  one thing is `...write to a textbox...`  you arent going to be able to do that from any sort of thread-based solution. I'd raise an event and supply the received data and let the consumer deal with it.

Comment: @Plutonix I'm not exactly sure how to simulate a DataReceived event in my code, and I'm trying to find the best way to do that. The app takes input from a textbox, sends it to the port, and then reads anything back from the port. Is there more information you need to be able to generally describe how one would go about doing this? Do my solutions above make sense?

Also, in multi-threaded applications I can use Invoke or something similar to write to form components, correct?

Comment: Can you use `Async/Await` (VS 2012+ / .NET 4.5+ - or 4.0 with some extra libs)?

Comment: @Mark Unfortunately the project is build around .NET 3.5, and I would rather not stray from that if possible.

Comment: you could have a class which represents the new serial API.  it could use a BGW to monitor the port(s). Use ReportProgress when data is received (whatever that means...1 char? 100?), then in the (private) ProgressChanged event raise a new DataReceived event which the form or class consumer could use.  The BGW event/method would simplify threading prevent having to define/pass/implement delegates; the events raised would be usable by the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but you could use a `BackgroundWorker` to do the IO.  e.g. something like this pseudo-code:

```
Public Class MyForm

    Private _port As ProprietaryIOLibrary
    Private WithEvents Worker As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        _port = New ProprietaryIOLibrary()
        Worker = New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker()
        Worker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        Worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        Worker.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonCancel.Click
        Worker.CancelAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Worker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles Worker.DoWork
        Do
            If _port.WaitForData(1000) Then ' Adjust timeout depending on cancel responsiveness?
                Dim data As String = _port.ReadDataAsString() ' ?
                ' Trigger the ProgressChanged event, passing the data
                Worker.ReportProgress(0, data)
            End If
            If Worker.CancellationPending Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End Sub

    Private Sub Worker_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles Worker.ProgressChanged
        ' Update the UI with the data received
        ' ProgressChanged is called on the UI thread, so no need to Invoke
        Dim data As String = DirectCast(e.UserState, String)
        TextBox1.Text &= data & vbCrLf
    End Sub

    Private Sub Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles Worker.RunWorkerCompleted
        TextBox1.Text &= "Complete!"
    End Sub

End Class
```